# login with another account inside iframe with next-auth?

Tags: reactjs, next.js, iframe, next-auth

I have an admin app that I login into to be able to see my dashboard , but I wanted to be able to login to another account within an iframe like code below here I get the jwt token session inside the url but how can i decode it and only login within the iframe ? is that the right way ?

```
 <Dialog    
   visible={visible}    
   style={{ width: '100vw', height: '100%' }}
    onHide={() => setVisible(false)}>
    {<iframe allowFullScreen src={`/mentor?token=${session}`} style={{ width: '100%', height: '100%', border: 'none' }}></iframe>}
  </Dialog>
```